# uCommerce Variant products

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore8.1, sitecore-ucommerce

I have around 4000 products, some of which have variants and some don't. I am getting an error when adding to basket that says

> The product with SKU '182929' contains variants, and cannot be added
>   the basket. Add a specific variant instead.

This error is received when I make this call:

```cs
TransactionLibrary.AddToBasket(1, "182929", null, null, null, true, true, null);
```

When I look at the product in the uCommerce interface there are no variants on it. Can someone tell me what determines whether the product is a variant or not? Or more to the point what would make uCommerce think this product has variants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uCommerce checks the definition of the product you're adding to verify that the product is "sellable". If the definition has any fields set up to be a variant property you cannot add the product family itself.

If you don't need the variant fields, you can remove the field in question. If you do, you need to use the product family SKU as well as the variant SKU in combination.

You can check your configuration in Settings / Definitions / Product Definitions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Spot on @Søren.  I have one definition "BaseProduct", then another for products without variants "PartyProducts" and a third "PartyProductVariants" for products with variants.  Somehow (I suspect during a uCommerce upgrade) definitions from PartyProductVariants were duplicated in the PartyProduct definition. Once removed all came good!  Thanks